# Explicit operator with reflection emit

Tags: c#

I have a class which I need to generate on the fly using reflection emit. I would like to be able to explicitly cast an instance of that class to a type defined at compile time.

I've tried to overload the explicit operator in my type defined with reflection emit to achieve this, but when it comes to casting it throws the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'MySourceClass' to type 'ExplictOperatorTest.MyTargetClass'.'

This is how I define the explicit operator using reflection emit:

```
private static void CreateExplicitOp(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, MethodInfo conversionMethod)
{
    var myType = typeBuilder.AsType();
    var method = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        "op_Explicit",
        MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.Static,
        typeof(MyTargetClass),
        new Type[] { myType });

    var ilGenerator = method.GetILGenerator();
    var emitRecordLocal = ilGenerator.DeclareLocal(typeof(MyTargetClass));
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilGenerator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, conversionMethod, new Type[] { });
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
}
```

And this is what I would like to do without error:

```
var mySourceTypeType = CreateMyType();
var mySourceTypeInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(mySourceTypeType);
// System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'MySourceClass' to type 'ExplictOperatorTest.MyTargetClass'.'
var myTarget = (MyTargetClass)mySourceTypeInstance;
```

I've compared my explicit declaration in IL with that generated from an equivalent pre-defined type and it looks much the same, and if I invoke the `op_Explicit` method directly then it works.

My question is: is what I want to do possible? If so, where am I going wrong?

Full repro:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/1AgRuJ

Comment: The problem is that `Activator.CreateInstance` returns `object`, not `MyType`. You'd get exactly the same problem if you had (say) `object x = new XElement("foo"); string y = (string) x;`. You could use `dynamic` instead... I'd expect that to work. (Basically, this isn't about the conversion operator you're emitting - it's about the behaviour of the cast in your last line. At least to start with - it may be that the conversion operator is broken too, but you're not finding that out yet.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, indeed the explicit cast works if I use `dynamic mySourceTypeInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(mySourceTypeType);` instead. Thanks.

Comment: Would you like me to basically turn my comment into an answer? It's not clear whether `dynamic` is suitable for your use case or not.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I am actually happy to use dynamic for my case. And of course just to understand why it didn't work having been looking in completely the wrong place. So yes, please do I would accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the *compile-time* type of `mySourceTypeInstance` is `object`, because that's the return type of `Activator.CreateInstance`. That means you're in a situation a bit like this:

```
object obj = new XElement("foo", "text content");
string text = (string) obj; // Throws InvalidCastException
```

That won't use the `XElement` explicit conversion to `string` because the conversion's availability is chosen at *compile time* based on the compile-time type of the expression.

If you want to move that binding decision to execution time though, you can use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic obj = new XElement("foo", "text content");
string text = (string) obj; // Works fine
```

So in your case, with your dynamically-generated/instantiated types, you'd use:

```
var mySourceTypeType = CreateMyType();
dynamic mySourceTypeInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(mySourceTypeType);
var myTarget = (MyTargetClass)mySourceTypeInstance;
```